# Differentiate puppet agent (with master) from puppet apply run?

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

Is it possible to differentiate a `puppet agent` run from a `puppet apply` run?
Is there a convenient environment variable or fact to check within my manifests?

Comment: Not convenient would be deriving this from $default_file_terminus value as they are different, but this is implicit dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$trusted['authenticated']` fact might work for you. The value will be:

- `local` for `puppet apply`
- `remote` (Or possibly `false`) for `puppet agent`

This is one of the *trusted facts* in puppet, check out the [official documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_facts_builtin_variables.html#trusted-facts).